# How to move focus from button to another button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I tried to focus or trigger but it's not working. Please let me know if you have any knowledge. Thanks in advance!

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
<button id="close-btn">Focus Button</button>


function myFunction() {
   let closeBtn = document.getElementById('close-btn');
       closeBtn.focus();
}
```

Comment: what do u mean with moving focus can u make ur question more clear?

Comment: sure, For example, I have one button. On click on that button is to open a modal and I want to move my focus from the first button to the modal close button. I'm working on ADA(Americans with Disabilities Act of 1990 (US)) so that's why I need to move the focus from the first button to the close button of the modal.

Comment: Seems to work in Safari, Chrome however not: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus#focus_on_a_button

Comment: @BilalRazzaq check out my suggested solution

Comment: if the button is in the modal you should trigger the focus on that **after** the modal has been shown. If you trigger it before it will then loose focus

Comment: Exactly @LelioFaieta you are right we need to add setTimeout and should trigger the focus on that after the modal has been shown. I used setTimeout and set focus on it and it works. Thanks!

Comment: you shouldn't use setTimeout but listen for the event that bubbles when the modal is shown. If you are using a library for modal that should be described. See for example bootstrap modals [in the Events section of the document](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)

Comment: @LelioFaieta I created a custom modal.

Answer (score 1):

This may solve your problem, the css part is just to show the effect.

```js
document.querySelector('#open-btn').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  document.querySelector('#close-btn').focus()
})
```

```css
button:focus {
    border: 2px solid rgb(54, 13, 13);
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<body>
      <button id="open-btn">Click</button>
      <button id="close-btn">Focus Button</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    .....
}
```

This will prevent the browser's default behavior of any element.

Thanks!